# CSS not resizing items in grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

My items within the grid are not re sizing for responsiveness in tablet and mobile view. They are looking cut off.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need to see a screen shot of what is occurring.

```css
.ch-grid {
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}
.ch-img-4 {
  background-image: url(images/4.jpg);
}
.ch-img-5 {
  background-image: url(images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-img-6 {
  background-image: url(images/6.jpg);
}
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url(images/2.jpg);
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(images/3.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*for a smooth font */
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 65px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: #fff222;
  color: rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.8);
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px rgba(0, 155, 222, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(0, 155, 222, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.mini-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-image section-g clearfix">
  <div class="image-wrapper col-md-6 col-sm-3 pull-left">
    <div class="background-image-wrapper wow slideInLeft">
      <img class="background-image" alt="" src="images/bg_01.jpg">
      <div class="mini-title">
        <ul class="ch-grid">
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-4">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Gail</h3>
                <p>mom</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-5">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Jeff</h3>
                <p>dad</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-6">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Heidi</h3>
                <p>equestrian</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ch-grid">
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Joey</h3>
                <p>drummer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-2">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Laura</h3>
                <p>soccer player</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Sara</h3>
                <p>artist</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end mini-title -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the "mom" and "dad" (etc) pieces of text that are being lost off of the bottom of each circle? If not, a screenshot might help.

Comment: It's not allowing me to post an image, but the text is appearing fine within the item, it's the actual images being cut off by the section to the right and or bottom when the site is resized.

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/K6sNvas and http://imgur.com/SmPPcqo - is this the same as what you're seeing?

Comment: Can you please update your code snippet so it contains some real images at the correct size. You can use something like this: http://placehold.it/350x166

Answer (score 1):

You can use vh and vw in order to display sizes according to viewport dimensions. This way, you can specify the height for your `h3` tag:

```
.ch-info h3 {
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-size: 22px;
      margin: 0 30px;
      padding: 65px 0 0 0;
      height: 15vh;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Or whatever you want.

> See the snippet for an exemple :

```css
.ch-grid {
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}
.ch-img-4 {
  background-image: url(images/4.jpg);
}
.ch-img-5 {
  background-image: url(images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-img-6 {
  background-image: url(images/6.jpg);
}
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url(images/2.jpg);
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(images/3.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*for a smooth font */
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 65px 0 0 0;
  height: 15vh;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: #fff222;
  color: rgba(247, 168, 0, 0.8);
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px rgba(0, 155, 222, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(0, 155, 222, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.mini-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-image section-g clearfix">
  <div class="image-wrapper col-md-6 col-sm-3 pull-left">
    <div class="background-image-wrapper wow slideInLeft">
      <img class="background-image" alt="" src="images/bg_01.jpg">
      <div class="mini-title">
        <ul class="ch-grid">
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-4">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Gail</h3>
                <p>mom</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-5">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Jeff</h3>
                <p>dad</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-6">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Heidi</h3>
                <p>equestrian</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ch-grid">
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Joey</h3>
                <p>drummer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-2">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Laura</h3>
                <p>soccer player</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>Sara</h3>
                <p>artist</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end mini-title -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

> EDIT: As @Jamie Barker noticed, this solution isn't 100% working, depending on viewport size. To prevent this behaviour, you can use media queries for tablets/phones, or `max-height`

Comment: If you run your code snippet and then click "Full page", you can see that unfortunately this isn't really working...

Comment: @Jamie Barker:  You're right. Didn't noticed this. Thanks. But are we not only supposed to give hints to OPs ? ;P - There are solutions to prevent this behaviour thankfully.

Comment: I realise this, which is why I deemed your post didn't suffice a down-vote ;). VW is a great method for keeping font sizes at the correct size, I've used it myself. It's only the statement "_See the **working** snippet :_" which messes with my chi :P

Comment: I completely agree with you. Updated wording ;)